# How can I access the data within the brackets under weather?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to access the data present within the weather sub category. but when i try to do so, i get the error that it is undefined. Is the JSON format wrong here and if not how can i access the data?

```
{ coord: { lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51 },
  weather: [ { id: 701, main: 'Mist', description: 'mist', icon: '50n' } ],
  base: 'stations',
  main: 
   { temp: 1.14,
     pressure: 1035,
     humidity: 100,
     temp_min: -2,
     temp_max: 4 },
  visibility: 8000,
  wind: { speed: 1.5, deg: 70 },
  clouds: { all: 0 },
  dt: 1545711600,
  sys: 
   { type: 1,
     id: 1414,
     message: 0.0034,
     country: 'GB',
     sunrise: 1545725128,
     sunset: 1545753355 },
  id: 2643743,
  name: 'London',
  cod: 200 }
```

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an array with one element in it, the first element of an array is index 0 and can be accessed like weather[0];

```js
const data = { coord: { lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51 },
  weather: [ { id: 701, main: 'Mist', description: 'mist', icon: '50n' } ],
  base: 'stations',
  main: 
   { temp: 1.14,
     pressure: 1035,
     humidity: 100,
     temp_min: -2,
     temp_max: 4 },
  visibility: 8000,
  wind: { speed: 1.5, deg: 70 },
  clouds: { all: 0 },
  dt: 1545711600,
  sys: 
   { type: 1,
     id: 1414,
     message: 0.0034,
     country: 'GB',
     sunrise: 1545725128,
     sunset: 1545753355 },
  id: 2643743,
  name: 'London',
  cod: 200 };
  
  
  console.log(data.weather[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

A useful site I was led to is http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
I use it for a lot of initial JSON trouble shooting. This JSON seams to be formatted fine. May I ask what you initially tried. Nevertheless this is how I would expect to access the values:

```
console.log(data.weather)
```

I've confirmed this in my browse console tool. I assigned the variable data with the JSON you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Store the json data in a variable, and use access data of weather just like we do in array.

```
const data = { 
  coord: { lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51 },
  weather: [ { id: 701, main: 'Mist', description: 'mist', icon: '50n' } ],
  base: 'stations',
  main: 
   { temp: 1.14,
     pressure: 1035,
     humidity: 100,
     temp_min: -2,
     temp_max: 4 },
  visibility: 8000,
  wind: { speed: 1.5, deg: 70 },
  clouds: { all: 0 },
  dt: 1545711600,
  sys: 
   { type: 1,
     id: 1414,
     message: 0.0034,
     country: 'GB',
     sunrise: 1545725128,
     sunset: 1545753355 },
  id: 2643743,
  name: 'London',
  cod: 200 }

console.log(data.weather[0]);
```